# How to know whether the numbers are in sequence or not

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question: **how would I determine whether numbers are in sequence or not?**

I have the data in one table (ex:source is the table). Assume that it contains the following data.

`account_ref` is the one column and `number` is another column.

```
Account_ref(varchar2(10))   number(varchar2(40))
101                         002
101                         003
101                         004
101                         006
101                         007
101                         008
101                         011
```

I am using `oracle 11gdb`,

I have tried by using the `listagg` with `','` separator.

it is giving the output with `002,003,004,006,007,008`

How can I determine that two numbers are in sequence?

The output something should be below

```
101 002-004
101 006-008
101 011
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure your example data makes any sense - your ifs all reference account_ref 101.

Comment: please suggest some thing..how to proceed

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what the output should look like for the input you have given?

Comment: (input):if account has 3  number in sequence then this numbers will be as follows:1) output should be in the  002-004 (2) if different then 011 etc (3) combinations it can exist both the sequenced and differnt numbers then output should be in 002-004,006-008,0011

Comment: And what is the datatype of the column that shows as 00XX?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORACLE SELECT GROUP BY + something that I don't know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521261/oracle-select-group-by-something-that-i-dont-know)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by values that are in sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977371/group-by-values-that-are-in-sequence)

Comment: Please help me out ...in finding the root cause to this solution..

Comment: Two possible solutions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38634/20